# Chain query/mutation calls with RTK Query using React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, rtk-query

In the example bellow I'm trying to create a simple login/authentication component with React and Redux Toolkit.

```js
const Login = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [login, { isLoading }] = useLoginMutation();
    const [loginData, setLoginData] = useState({
        email: '',
        password: '',
    });

    const loginHandler = async () => {
        try {
            const result = await login({
                email: loginData.email,
                password: loginData.password,
            }).unwrap();

            const { token, userId } = result;

            const { data } = await dispatch(
                backendApi.endpoints.getUser.initiate({ token, userId })
            );

            dispatch(
                setCredentials({
                    user: {
                        email: data.user.email,
                        id: data.user.id,
                        name: data.user.name,
                        type: data.user.type,
                    },
                    token,
                })
            );
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    };

    return (
        <Space>
            {isLoading ? (
                <SpinnerIcon />
            ) : (
                // setLoginData and loginHandler are set and used here
                // Standard React code: Input onChange -> setLoginData / Submit button onClick -> loginHandler
                // (nothing special, code shortened for the sake of readability)
                <FormWithEmailPasswordInputsAndButton />
            )}
        </Space>
    );
};
```

This works fine, the problem is that:

I want to make use of the `isLoading` property on the `getUser` query result object so that the `<SpinnerIcon />` component will be visible until both requests are done.

As it is, the `spinnerIcon` component is only shown during the `login` API call because I'm not using React Hooks to call `getUser` query therefore I don't have the `isLoading` property from `getUser` available to the rest of the component.

But if I want to use React Hooks to make the call I'll need the result from the `login` mutation beforehand.

`const [getUser, { isLoading: isUserLoading }] = useGetUserQuery(resultFromLoginMutation);`

And I don't know how to do that. One after the other, so that I can make use of both `isLoading` properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `skipToken` or the `skip` option:

```js
const [login, { isLoading, data: resultFromLoginMutation, isSuccess }] = useLoginMutation();
const [getUser, { isLoading: isUserLoading }] = useGetUserQuery(resultFromLoginMutation, { skip: !isSuccess });
```

or

```js
const [login, { isLoading, data: resultFromLoginMutation }] = useLoginMutation();
const [getUser, { isLoading: isUserLoading }] = useGetUserQuery(resultFromLoginMutation ?? skipToken);
```

Comment: Thanks @phry, just one caveat, the useQuery hook doesn't seem to return an array, so I had to call it as:
`const { isLoading: isUserLoading, data: resultFromGetUserQuery } = useGetUserQuery(
        resultFromLoginMutation,
        {
            skip: !isSuccess,
        }
    );`

Comment: However I'm still getting a TS error about the `resultFromLoginMutation`:
`Argument of type 'authData | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'authData | unique symbol'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'authData | unique symbol'.ts(2345)`

Because `resultFromLoginMutation` is possibly undefined when it's passed to `useGetUserQuery`. Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: Also, thank you for your YouTube videos, they were really helpful. Before writing this question on SO I thought of writing you an e-mail but figured that would be too intrusive, plus I saw you were pretty active here on SO so I had a feeling you'd show up eventually hahaha.

Comment: As for your current error: you probably want to go the `?? skipToken` route - that just works better with TS.

Comment: For questions, your best bet is either SO, the RTK "Disussions" section in github or the redux chat in Reactiflux. Many RTKQ users there too.